# Using resource names in WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, embedded-resource

In WinAPI, you can access resources via [`FindResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`LoadResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046(v=vs.85).aspx).

According to [the documentation for `FindResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042(v=vs.85).aspx), you can specify the name of the resource:

> lpName [in]
>
> Type: LPCTSTR
>
> The name of the resource. Alternately, rather than a pointer, this parameter can be MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID), where ID is the integer identifier of the resource. For more information, see the Remarks section below.

I have two questions:

First, this doesn't even seem to be accurate because neither specifying the ID or file name worked.  What is the proper value to input for the `lpName` argument? 
*[This other question seemed to have this issue as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807554/findresource-fails)*

Second, I want to know if it is possible to retrieve the file name for the resource at run-time.  Is this possible?  Or is the file name discarded once the file is packaged as a resource?

#### Test Code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "resource.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    //This is the only test that succeeds.
    if (!FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_DRAWING1), _T("BINARY")))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_DRAWING1); BINARY"), _T(""), MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    //This one fails.
    if (!FindResource(hInstance, _T("IDR_DRAWING1"), _T("BINARY")))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("\"IDR_DRAWING1\"; BINARY"), _T(""), MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    //ICON - Each fails.
    if (!FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1), _T("ICON")))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1); ICON"), _T(""), MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    if (!FindResource(hInstance, _T("IDI_ICON1"), _T("ICON")))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("\"IDI_ICON1\"; ICON"), _T(""), MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    if (!FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1), RT_ICON))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1); RT_ICON"), _T(""), MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    if (!FindResource(hInstance, _T("IDI_ICON1"), RT_ICON))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("\"IDI_ICON1\"; RT_ICON"), _T(""), MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    //HTML - Each fails.
    if (!FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_HTML1), _T("HTML")))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_HTML1); HTML"), _T(""), MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    if (!FindResource(hInstance, _T("IDR_HTML1"), _T("HTML")))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("\"IDR_HTML1\"; HTML"), _T(""), MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    if (!FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_HTML1), RT_HTML))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_HTML1); RT_HTML"), _T(""), MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    if (!FindResource(hInstance, _T("IDR_HTML1"), RT_HTML))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("\"IDR_HTML1\"; RT_HTML"), _T(""), MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Resource.rc**

This isn't the entire file because it contains a lot of boiler-plate code.  Here are the relevant resource declarations.

```
IDR_DRAWING1            BINARY                  "Drawing1.dwg"
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "icon1.ico"
IDR_HTML1               HTML                    "html1.htm"
```

The .ico and the .htm were created automatically using Visual Studio;  by adding new resources of the corresponding type.  So their format shouldn't be messing up the `FindResource` statement.

**resource.h**

```
#define IDR_DRAWING1                    101
#define IDI_ICON1                       102
#define IDR_HTML1                       103
```

> #### EDIT:
>
> Per Ben Voigt's comment, I've gone ahead and changed the **Resource.rc** file so non-numeric names are used:
>
> ```
> DWG1                    BINARY                  "Drawing1.dwg"
> ICON1                   ICON                    "icon1.ico"
> HTML1                   HTML                    "html1.htm"
> ```
>
> Now, the **resource.h** file isn't used at all.  Following are the new relevant tests:
>
> ```
> FindResource(hInstance, _T("DWG1"), _T("BINARY")); //Succeeds now.
> FindResource(hInstance, _T("ICON1"), _T("ICON")); //Still fails.
> FindResource(hInstance, _T("ICON1"), RT_ICON); //Still fails.
> FindResource(hInstance, _T("HTML1"), _T("HTML")); //Still fails.
> FindResource(hInstance, _T("HTML1"), RT_HTML); //Still fails.
> ```
>
> So, my expectations are met for my binary resource, but what is happening with the `ICON` and `HTML`?

Comment: The documentation is accurate. Your understanding is flawed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan while I appreciate your feedback, that doesn't help me understand any better.  Like I said, I couldn't get it to work with either value.  I will tinker with it some more and update my post with code.

Comment: If you showed your .rc file and you code, then we could be more detailed in our responses.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Done, there's 10 tests to show what worked and what didn't.  Only the first test succeeds.

Comment: Please show the declarations that are relevant in `resource.h`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  I've added it now, but it doesn't seem like anything special.

Comment: Looking at your new edit, I think you need `RT_GROUP_ICON`, maybe `RT_ANIICON`

Comment: Yep, `RT_GROUP_ICON` did the trick.  `RT_ICON` is hardware-dependent according to the docs.  No idea why my PC's hardware doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution and Results:

Okay, so I've finally got a predictable results.

The way you find the resource is partially dependent on the resource type.  In this case, `DWG1` is a `BINARY` resource which is a custom type.  There does not exist a predefined `RT_*` among the [resource types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648009(v=vs.85).aspx), so you will need to specify the type as an `LPCTSTR`:

```
FindResource(hInstance, _T("DWG1"), _T("BINARY"));
```

For a predefined resource type, you cannot specify the type name as a `LPCTSTR`. Instead you must use the corresponding `RT_*` value.  This is probably because each `RT_*` value corresponds to a `MAKEINTRESOURCE(WORD)`, and if my understanding is correct, that macro result points to an invalid address within the [portable executable file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable), not to a textual representation of the resource type.

[*This questions addresses MAKEINTRESOURCE*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3610565/975724)

The issue with the `ICON1` resource was that the type should have been `RT_GROUP_ICON` instead of `RT_ICON`.  The difference of these two types is that the former is hardware-independent and the latter is hardware-dependent.  Though, I do not know why `RT_ICON` didn't work.

Last, the issue with `HTML1` was a fault on my part because I hadn't made sure that the referenced file actually had data.  During the build, it was probably omitted since it was essentially a null resource.  The correct type to use for this resource is `RT_HTML`.

Now, in regards to the names.  As mentioned by Ben Voigt in a comment to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28734925/975724), non-numeric names are required in order to specify the name as a `LPCTSTR`.  If numeric names are used, then one must use `MAKEINTRESOURCE` instead.

Visual Studio's resource editor makes it a bit cumbersome to name resources with strings instead of numbers, since by default it creates macros for each resource.  These macros then replace the resource name with a number during the preprocessing phase.

In order to change the name into a string, you have 2 options:

- Surround the `ID` of the resource (found in the properties) with double quotes.  This prevents the resource editor from creating a macro for the name.  However, a macro might already exist if quotations were placed around a previously set `ID`.

[image: Resource Properties]

- Alternatively, open the resource script file in any text editor and choose the name like that.  Again the idea is to prevent a macro from being generated.  So detaching the the resource script and resource header would work, or simply make sure the macro doesn't exist in the header.

Comment: "I do not know why RT_ICON didn't work"  The resources are arranged in a nested structure, think of it as a directory for each type, with named/numbered resources inside.  If you look in the wrong directory, you won't find the resource.  This allows giving the same name/number to related resources, such as main window icon, main window menu, main window accelerators.  If it went the other way, and the name/number identified the resource, then an attempt could be made to convert to the requested type.  But that design decision is ancient history now.

Comment: "that macro result points to an invalid address within the PE file"... well, sort of.  Windows tests whether the high bits are all zero, and if they are, treats it as a numeric resource.  By a happy coincidence, pointer values with all-zero high bits are made illegal to help catch NULL pointer errors.  So there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

> is the file name discarded once the file is packaged as a resource?

Yes, exactly.

For example, in the [ICON statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381018%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the first column is the resource name, and the third column is the filename..

```
nameID ICON filename
```

And some resources don't come from external files at all, for example the [MENU statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets its data from nested `MENU` and `MENUITEM` statements directly in the resource script.  `DIALOG`, `STRINGTABLE`, `VERSION`, and `VERSIONINFO` are just a few of the other common resources that don't exist as separate files.

Comment: I've posted some test code to my OP demonstrating what works and what doesn't.  Apparently, none of the statements accept the `nameID` as described in your answer.

Comment: @NickMiller: After preprocessing, your file is `101 BINARY "Drawing1.dwg"` etc.  You've used numeric IDs without any name.  So no name is available at runtime.  If you didn't have a macro definition, then the resource would actually be named `IDR_DRAWING1`

Comment: Again thanks for the help, however that doesn't seem to be sufficient.  I've added more tests to the OP and only the `BINARY` resource is found.   The `ICON` and `HTML` still fail.

Comment: @NickMiller: Well, open your module (EXE or DLL) up in the resource editor and see what the actual resource names are.  (Or use `EnumResourceTypes` and `EnumResourceNames`, but for a quick test it's a lot easier to use an existing tool)

Comment: Thanks for all your help Ben!  I have learned quite a bit on how resources work.